# Sending Google Calendar API Confirmation email

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to make it so that once an event is created with Google Calendar API and an attendee is added, they will get a confirmation email.

Is this possible with the current Google Calendar API? (I'm using PHP for the back end ). I've tried  with `sendUpdates` set to all and `attendees[].responseStatus` to `needsAction` but without any success.

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' =>'something',
  'location' => 'something',
  'description' => $name.' test',
  'start' => array(
    // 'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'dateTime' => $start.':00-04:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $end.':00-04:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => $email),
    'responseStatus' => 'needsAction',
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
  'sendUpdates' => 'all',
  'visibility' => 'public',
));

$calendarId = 'vladc99@gmail.com';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
echo "<a href='".$event->htmlLink."' taget='_blank'> Click here </a>";
echo "<a href='../'>Home</a>";
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `sendUpdates` is a request parameter, not an option of the request body

In other words it is not located inside the request body.

Modify your code as following:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' =>'something',
  'location' => 'something',
  'description' => $name.' test',
  'start' => array(
    // 'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'dateTime' => $start.':00-04:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $end.':00-04:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Toronto',
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => $email),
    'responseStatus' => 'needsAction',
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
  'visibility' => 'public',
));

$calendarId = 'vladc99@gmail.com';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, array('sendUpdates' => 'all'));
echo "<a href='".$event->htmlLink."' taget='_blank'> Click here </a>";
echo "<a href='../'>Home</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have implemented same code, and event is created but confirmation mail is not send so could you please tell me where is the issue? below is question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62713545/why-google-calendar-event-invite-mail-not-send-to-there-guests-when-event-is-cre