# Why google calendar event invite mail not send to there guests when event is create?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to send google calendar event email to multiple users by their emails. Currently event is created but mail not send to guest users that we have added in this event. So want to send an email to guest users when event is created. So can you please help me that why mail is not send?

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/*if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}*/

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ .'/credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

// Refer to the PHP quickstart on how to setup the environment:
// https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php
// Change the scope to Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR and delete any stored
// credentials.

$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Test Event',
  'location' => 'Test Event',
  'description' => 'This is my test description',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-05-21T04:02:00-04:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2020-05-22T16:05:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lorit12866@frost2d.net'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, ['sendUpdates' => 'all']);
//$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have added code here, so that anyone can see where actually issue is occur

Comment: Is your problem related to not getting a notification when creating the event or not getting a reminder one day before the event?

Comment: Yes, it is my issue

Comment: Which of the two?

Comment: You are **not** running this through a web browser, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If your problem is related to the attendees not receiving the reminder 24 hours before the event:**

Mind that the overwriting the default reminders only works for the event creator.

As you can verifiy under [Private event properties](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/sharing#private_event_properties):

> Some properties are private, such as reminders, colorId, transparency,
> or the extendedProperties.private property. These properties are
> controlled by the attendee's settings and not by the organizer
> calendar.

In other words, the attendees will receive (or not receive) the reminders according to their settings in their calendar, you cannot force a reminder on them.

**If you problem is related to the attendees not receiving the notification when you create the alarm:**

- Mind that you specified an event start and end date lying in the past
- Notifications will only be sent out when you create an event taking place in the future